# Touch screen driver not initializing on first boot, subsequent boots work however

Tags: files, raspbian, touch-screen

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 3 with a Pi TFT+ 3.5" display. -- I figured this is more of a Linux Question than anything else though.

It works fine when I use the suggested image for the device -- it works.

My issue is,the first time I boot up the device, the screen works but not the touch portion. If I hard reboot it, the second boot works, always. And if I want to reboot again, I have to do it twice again.

It seems like it has something to do with the files (or links?) in the /dev/input directory.

On the working system, when I run `ls` on `/dev/input` I get the following attached picture as output.
[image: http://imgur.com/a/r3Rk2]

However, when the system is not working, and I've run that command, the only thing that shows up under `/dev/input` is `mouse0`, so obviously those links and files are getting deleted? I'm not sure.

Do you have any ideas what is happening in that directory? I am not making any changes at all that would force a config change.

EDIT: here is the dmesg output.

Not working:
http://pastebin.com/BMCcaZh6

Working:
http://pastebin.com/ZqNAczXZ

Comment: Have a look at `dmesg` output and/or `syslog`, and compare the working one with the one when it doesn't work. Very likely you'll see error messages that give a clue about what happened. "Missing" entries in `/dev/input` after boot point to drivers not loading properly, for whatever reason. All files in `/dev/input` are *created*  when the driver loads (via `udev`), on boot or later, nobody maliciously deletes them. :-)

Comment: @dirkt, this is my output that I get when running dmesg. http://imgur.com/tmTfnzE

Comment: A screenshot of the end of a single output with all the interesting parts missing doesn't really help ... As I said, **compare** the output of the **working** one with the **bad** one. That manes **two** outputs, obviously. You can use `dmesg > some_file` to save the output as text, `cut` to remove the time stamps, and `diff` to look for differences (`man cut`, `man diff` for details). Even better, **read** through the output and look for the part that deals with the touchscreen in both. And use a pastebin instead of imgur :-) One can't work with images of text.

Comment: @dirkt I added the outputs in the main question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

If you compare them, you'll see that in the "working" variant,

```
[    4.478652] stmpe-spi spi0.1: stmpe610 detected, chip id: 0x811
[    4.496482] input: stmpe-ts as /devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.1/stmpe-ts/input/input0
```

while in the "not working" variant,

```
[    5.560311] stmpe-spi spi0.1: unknown chip id: 0x0
[    5.560351] stmpe-spi: probe of spi0.1 failed with error -22
```

Googling for "stmpe610" shows that this is indeed a resistive touch screen controller chip. So this chip sits on an [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) bus, and is for some reason not detected on first boot.

Could be a timing issue, could be a missing initialization that happens later for some reason, could be something else.

I assume you do have a module called `stmpe-spi` or similar (check in `/lib/modules`). In the "not working" state, can you `modprobe stmpe-spi` after it finished booting, and does it recognize the chip then (check `dmesg`)?

Comment: when I run modprobe, I get `modprobe: FATAL: Module stmpe-spi not found.` In the non-working version, I cannot seem to find the stmpe-spi module either.

Comment: Going by the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/stmpe-spi.c), it definitely can be compiled as module. I don't have a RaspPi, so I don't know what the exact kernel config option is, or what the exact name of the compiled module is. Did you look in `/lib/modules` for a **similar** name as I wrote? If there's none there, can you compile your own RaspPi kernel, and configure it as module? It would make debugging easier.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6sAV2E82 this is the output I get when searching for files containing `smtpe` @dirkt

Comment: So, did you try to modprobe `smtpe-ts`? (Do I really have to prompt you for every single step? Come on, do a bit of thinking on your own.)

Comment: sorry, didn't know asking for help on a help website was a problem. Im not a Linux expert.

Comment: It's not a problem, but a "I'm just going to do the simplest part of what you explained, I'll ignore all the other information you gave and make you ask me again" is going to take a long time if we do it that way, and it's not really suitable for the Q&A format of this site. I don't have a ready-made answer for your problem. Debugging is a *process*: You'll have to test hypthesis after hypothesis, you'll have to *look* at the information, read and understand it. You'll need to figure things out and *become* an expert. I can point you in the right direction, but you'll have to walk yourself.